# how to list files in linux based on pattern using bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have some files (a lot like 2000 files) starting with `b00123420151110121120.ext.123342` where `b00+id+datetime(YmdHms).ext.id2`.
I need to list only files from some dates like ...20151106... i don't care about anything else like id or hourminutesecond, only yearMonthDay.

I tried combination using awk and grep but it seems not workin

`ls -1 dir/* | grep "20151106"`

`ls -1 dir/* | grep "*20151106*"`

Thank you

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: I tried some awk found on internet but i can't seem to make it work.

Comment: Could you please post it in your question?

Comment: grep also not working

Comment: Grep is working fine, but grep uses [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). `*` is [glob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) wildcard, you want `.` in regexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your id is 4-digit you can use

```
ls b00????20151106*
```

to get files with certain date

```
ls b00????201?1106*
```

to get files from 1106 for all 201? years

```
ls b00????201[45]*
```

to get all files for years 2014 and 2015 etc

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that works with any id length:

```
find dir -regex '.*b00.*20151110......\.ext.*'
```

It works by matching from the end: we know the date is followed by `.ext` and we don’t care about hours, minutes and seconds. We can use 6 dots to match hhmmss. Here is how the pattern works:

```
.*      # match anything before, e.g. the name of the directory
b00     # file prefix
.*      # id
2015    # year
11      # month
10      # day
..      # hour
..      # minutes
..      # seconds
\.ext.* # rest of the filename
```

You can change the pattern to match on periods, e.g. use `..` for the day to have all files for the month, use `..` for both the month and the day to have the full year, etc.